# The question during installing the TestLink

Tags: windows

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "results" on
> null in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php:409 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\install\index.php(20): require_once() #1
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php on line
> 409

I have tried to update the log_path and repositoryPath.